# How to create a square size camera for android

Tags: android, android-camera

Please tell me how to create a square size camera in my android application as in instagram? I was looking for a solution for a very long time, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you just use an overlay on top of the camera view. Then crop the photo later

Comment: And there is no way to directly using a camera do this?

Comment: Note that Instagram has relieved this restriction and now accepts oblong images ;-)

Comment: Kindly check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176270/android-camera-preview-on-a-square-screen-stretched/35054199#35054199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create an square size camera its totally depends upon the device.

> Basically every device have their own camera sizes you can get the
>   list of all the device's size and then set your prefer one...!

Here is a camera preview class which auto set the good size to the camera view,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
/**
 * This class assumes the parent layout is RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static boolean DEBUGGING = true;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CameraPreviewSample";
    private static final String CAMERA_PARAM_ORIENTATION = "orientation";
    private static final String CAMERA_PARAM_LANDSCAPE = "landscape";
    private static final String CAMERA_PARAM_PORTRAIT = "portrait";
    protected CameraActivity mActivity;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    protected Camera mCamera;
    protected List<Camera.Size> mPreviewSizeList;
    protected List<Camera.Size> mPictureSizeList;
    protected Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
    protected Camera.Size mPictureSize;
    private int mSurfaceChangedCallDepth = 0;
    private int mCameraId;
    private LayoutMode mLayoutMode;
    private int mCenterPosX = -1;
    private int mCenterPosY;
    public static boolean isSafeForTakeImage = false;

    PreviewReadyCallback mPreviewReadyCallback = null;

    public static enum LayoutMode 
    {
        FitToParent, // Scale to the size that no side is larger than the parent
        NoBlank // Scale to the size that no side is smaller than the parent
    };

    public interface PreviewReadyCallback {
        public void onPreviewReady();
    }

    /**
     * State flag: true when surface's layout size is set and surfaceChanged()
     * process has not been completed.
     */
    protected boolean mSurfaceConfiguring = false;

    public CameraPreview(CameraActivity activity, int cameraId, LayoutMode mode) {
        super(activity); // Always necessary
        mActivity = activity;
        mLayoutMode = mode;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > cameraId) {
                mCameraId = cameraId;
            } else {
                mCameraId = 0;
            }
        } else {
            mCameraId = 0;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            mCamera = Camera.open(mCameraId);
        } else {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        }
        Camera.Parameters cameraParams = mCamera.getParameters();
        mPreviewSizeList = cameraParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        mPictureSizeList = cameraParams.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try 
        {
            isSafeForTakeImage = true;
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        mSurfaceChangedCallDepth++;
        doSurfaceChanged(width, height);
        mSurfaceChangedCallDepth--;
    }

    private void doSurfaceChanged(int width, int height) 
    {
        isSafeForTakeImage = false;

        mCamera.stopPreview();

        Camera.Parameters cameraParams = mCamera.getParameters();
       // cameraParams.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
       if(cameraParams.getSupportedFocusModes() != null 
               && cameraParams.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE))
       {
            cameraParams.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
       }

        cameraParams.setRotation(90);
        boolean portrait = isPortrait();

        // The code in this if-statement is prevented from executed again when surfaceChanged is
        // called again due to the change of the layout size in this if-statement.
        if (!mSurfaceConfiguring) {
            Camera.Size previewSize = determinePreviewSize(portrait, width, height);
            Camera.Size pictureSize = determinePictureSize(previewSize);
            if (DEBUGGING) { Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Desired Preview Size - w: " + width + ", h: " + height); }
            mPreviewSize = previewSize;
            mPictureSize = pictureSize;
//            mSurfaceConfiguring = adjustSurfaceLayoutSize(previewSize, portrait, width, height);

            // Continue executing this method if this method is called recursively.
            // Recursive call of surfaceChanged is very special case, which is a path from
            // the catch clause at the end of this method.
            // The later part of this method should be executed as well in the recursive
            // invocation of this method, because the layout change made in this recursive
            // call will not trigger another invocation of this method.
            if (mSurfaceConfiguring && (mSurfaceChangedCallDepth <= 1)) {
                return;
            }

        }

        configureCameraParameters(cameraParams, portrait);
        mSurfaceConfiguring = false;

        try {
            mCamera.startPreview();
            isSafeForTakeImage = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Failed to start preview: " + e.getMessage());

            // Remove failed size
            mPreviewSizeList.remove(mPreviewSize);
            mPreviewSize = null;

            // Reconfigure
            if (mPreviewSizeList.size() > 0) { // prevent infinite loop
                surfaceChanged(null, 0, width, height);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Can't start preview", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Gave up starting preview");
            }
        }

        if (null != mPreviewReadyCallback) {
            mPreviewReadyCallback.onPreviewReady();
        }

        //TODO
        mActivity.setMyCamera(mCamera);
    }

    /**
     * @param cameraParams
     * @param portrait
     * @param reqWidth must be the value of the parameter passed in surfaceChanged
     * @param reqHeight must be the value of the parameter passed in surfaceChanged
     * @return Camera.Size object that is an element of the list returned from Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes.
     */
    protected Camera.Size determinePreviewSize(boolean portrait, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Meaning of width and height is switched for preview when portrait,
        // while it is the same as user's view for surface and metrics.
        // That is, width must always be larger than height for setPreviewSize.
        int reqPreviewWidth; // requested width in terms of camera hardware
        int reqPreviewHeight; // requested height in terms of camera hardware
        if (portrait) {
            reqPreviewWidth = reqHeight;
            reqPreviewHeight = reqWidth;
        } else {
            reqPreviewWidth = reqWidth;
            reqPreviewHeight = reqHeight;
        }

        if (DEBUGGING) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Listing all supported preview sizes");
            for (Camera.Size size : mPreviewSizeList) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "  w: " + size.width + ", h: " + size.height);
            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Listing all supported picture sizes");
            for (Camera.Size size : mPictureSizeList) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "  w: " + size.width + ", h: " + size.height);
            }
        }

        // Adjust surface size with the closest aspect-ratio
        float reqRatio = ((float) reqPreviewWidth) / reqPreviewHeight;
        float curRatio, deltaRatio;
        float deltaRatioMin = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        Camera.Size retSize = null;
        for (Camera.Size size : mPreviewSizeList) {
            curRatio = ((float) size.width) / size.height;
            deltaRatio = Math.abs(reqRatio - curRatio);
            if (deltaRatio < deltaRatioMin) {
                deltaRatioMin = deltaRatio;
                retSize = size;
            }
        }

        return retSize;
    }

    protected Camera.Size determinePictureSize(Camera.Size previewSize) {
        Camera.Size retSize = null;
        for (Camera.Size size : mPictureSizeList) {
            if (size.equals(previewSize)) {
                return size;
            }
        }

        if (DEBUGGING) { Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Same picture size not found."); }

        // if the preview size is not supported as a picture size
        float reqRatio = ((float) previewSize.width) / previewSize.height;
        float curRatio, deltaRatio;
        float deltaRatioMin = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : mPictureSizeList) {
            curRatio = ((float) size.width) / size.height;
            deltaRatio = Math.abs(reqRatio - curRatio);
            if (deltaRatio < deltaRatioMin) {
                deltaRatioMin = deltaRatio;
                retSize = size;
            }
        }

        return retSize;
    }

    protected boolean adjustSurfaceLayoutSize(Camera.Size previewSize, boolean portrait,
            int availableWidth, int availableHeight) {
        float tmpLayoutHeight, tmpLayoutWidth;
        if (portrait) {
            tmpLayoutHeight = previewSize.width;
            tmpLayoutWidth = previewSize.height;
        } else {
            tmpLayoutHeight = previewSize.height;
            tmpLayoutWidth = previewSize.width;
        }

        float factH, factW, fact;
        factH = availableHeight / tmpLayoutHeight;
        factW = availableWidth / tmpLayoutWidth;
        if (mLayoutMode == LayoutMode.FitToParent) {
            // Select smaller factor, because the surface cannot be set to the size larger than display metrics.
            if (factH < factW) {
                fact = factH;
            } else {
                fact = factW;
            }
        } else {
            if (factH < factW) {
                fact = factW;
            } else {
                fact = factH;
            }
        }

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams();

        int layoutHeight = (int) (tmpLayoutHeight * fact);
        int layoutWidth = (int) (tmpLayoutWidth * fact);
        if (DEBUGGING) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Preview Layout Size - w: " + layoutWidth + ", h: " + layoutHeight);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Scale factor: " + fact);
        }

        boolean layoutChanged;
        if ((layoutWidth != this.getWidth()) || (layoutHeight != this.getHeight())) {
            layoutParams.height = layoutHeight;
            layoutParams.width = layoutWidth;
            if (mCenterPosX >= 0) {
                layoutParams.topMargin = mCenterPosY - (layoutHeight / 2);
                layoutParams.leftMargin = mCenterPosX - (layoutWidth / 2);
            }
            this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); // this will trigger another surfaceChanged invocation.
            layoutChanged = true;
        } else {
            layoutChanged = false;
        }

        return layoutChanged;
    }

    /**
     * @param x X coordinate of center position on the screen. Set to negative value to unset.
     * @param y Y coordinate of center position on the screen.
     */
    public void setCenterPosition(int x, int y) {
        mCenterPosX = x;
        mCenterPosY = y;
    }

    protected void configureCameraParameters(Camera.Parameters cameraParams, boolean portrait) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) { // for 2.1 and before
            if (portrait) 
            {
                cameraParams.set(CAMERA_PARAM_ORIENTATION, CAMERA_PARAM_PORTRAIT);
            } 
            else 
            {
                cameraParams.set(CAMERA_PARAM_ORIENTATION, CAMERA_PARAM_LANDSCAPE);
            }
        } else { // for 2.2 and later
            int angle;
            Display display = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            switch (display.getRotation()) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0: // This is display orientation
                    angle = 90; // This is camera orientation
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    angle = 0;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    angle = 270;
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    angle = 180;
                    break;
                default:
                    angle = 90;
                    break;
            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "angle: " + angle);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(angle);
        }

        cameraParams.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        cameraParams.setPictureSize(mPictureSize.width, mPictureSize.height);
        if (DEBUGGING) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Preview Actual Size - w: " + mPreviewSize.width + ", h: " + mPreviewSize.height);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Picture Actual Size - w: " + mPictureSize.width + ", h: " + mPictureSize.height);
        }
        mCamera.setParameters(cameraParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        stop();
        isSafeForTakeImage = false;
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (null == mCamera) {
            return;
        }
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    public boolean isPortrait() {
        return (mActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    public void setOneShotPreviewCallback(PreviewCallback callback) {
        if (null == mCamera) {
            return;
        }
        mCamera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(callback);
    }

    public void setPreviewCallback(PreviewCallback callback) {
        if (null == mCamera) {
            return;
        }
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(callback);
    }

    public Camera.Size getPreviewSize() {
        return mPreviewSize;
    }

    public void setOnPreviewReady(PreviewReadyCallback cb) {
        mPreviewReadyCallback = cb;
    }

}
```

You need the below permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```

The above class assume, you are using relative layout,
In your activity put this code in your onResume() method,

```
surfaceview = new CameraPreview(this, 0, CameraPreview.LayoutMode.FitToParent);
                 LayoutParams previewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                 previewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                 relativeLayout.addView(surfaceview, 0, previewLayoutParams);
```

Add below lines in your onPause() method

```
try{
     relativeLayout.removeView(surfaceview);
}catch(Exception exception){
}
```

Comment: on which click photo is capturing in this

Comment: You need to define the callback...!